# Graphical solution to vectors

Tags: vectors

I have completed a task, and now need to create a graphical solution. This is where i am stuck. As i have i,j and k. Is this because its 3D? As i have only seen 2 whilst looking for a solution.

This is my competed answer. I am just looking for help to represent this graphically.

The body is in equilibrium because:
$$(6i + 7j – 5k) + (-18i – 38j – 14k) + (-18i + 25j + 24k) + (30i + +6j – 5k)
= 0i + 0j + 0k = 0$$

I have this:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G5zwq.png)

Is this correct? If not what have i done wrong? And how do i finish it to look like yours?

Comment: I will recommend GeoGebra tool, it is FREE and you can visualize many math subjects there. For your information I prefer classic GeoGebra 5...

Comment: Thank  you. I will look at this and see if i can use it#

Comment: I guess i,j,k = x,y,z. so would i draw 6i, then -18i, -18i then +30i. Draw this to prove it = 0. ?

Comment: Hmm, for your information $\vec{i}, \vec{j}, \vec{k}$ are the unit vectors in the direction of the $x$, $y$, and $z$ axes of a three dimensional Cartesian coordinate system... In order to continue, I suggest to learn more about vectors, for example wikipedia may be helpful: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space
Next, addition of vectors will be in your focus...

Answer (score 1):

Here is my work in GeoGebra ([www.geogebra.org](http://www.geogebra.org)): [image: My work in GeoGebra]

Comment: I have read and understand more now. But can i ask how this proves they all add up to 0?

Comment: See vector $\vec{a}+\vec{b}+\vec{c}$ (pink one), it is just opposite vector to vector $\vec{d}$, what is enough to conclude that their sum is null-vector $\vec{0}$.